# EndyJasmi\Cuid::random() error after running migrations

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to run the migrations of my project and I got this error.

```
   ErrorException  : Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored    

  at C:\Users\josed\OneDrive\Documentos\123workforce\resume-manager\vendor\endyjasmi\cuid\src\Cuid.php:136
    132|         $hash = Cuid::pad(
    133|             base_convert(
    134|                 $random,
    135|                 Cuid::DECIMAL,
  > 136|                 Cuid::BASE36
    137|             ),
    138|             Cuid::NORMAL_BLOCK
    139|         );
    140| 

  Exception trace:

  1   base_convert("206539.96658633")
      C:\Users\josed\OneDrive\Documentos\123workforce\resume-manager\vendor\endyjasmi\cuid\src\Cuid.php:136

  2   EndyJasmi\Cuid::random()
      C:\Users\josed\OneDrive\Documentos\123workforce\resume-manager\vendor\endyjasmi\cuid\src\Cuid.php:192

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

I cloned and run `composer install`. I when I execute `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` I got this.
I installed again the dependencies, drop and run again `composer install`, and deleted from composer.json cuid package.

Comment: show your migrations files and your Constants values.

Comment: base_convert ignores `.` character in $random string and emits Deprecation notice in PHP 7.4

Comment: How can I change it? I don't see where the error is ocurring

Answer (score 0):

This error was fixed by https://github.com/endyjasmi/cuid/pull/8 but it hasn't been released yet.
Set version constraint of `endyjasmi/cuid` package to `dev-master` until it is released.

Comment: Meanwhile I changed my php version to 7.3